# Deriving the torque equation

Tags: angular-momentum, torque

I have been reading Goldstein's textbook on classical mechanics, and the deriving of the torque equation has me slightly confused.
The equation is as such :
$$  N=\frac{d(r ×mv_2)}{dt}$$
$$ N =(\frac{dr}{dt} ×mv_2) + (r × \frac{d(mv_2)}{dt})$$
$$ N =(v_1 ×mv_2)+(r × \frac{d(mv_2)}{dt}) $$
Where
$$v_1×mv_2 = 0$$
But, I am unconvinced that both v refer to the same thing, as V1 is the result of a differential of r, hence it should be in the same direction as r, whereas V2 refers to the veloctiy of the particle when it is in motion about a point, so it should be perpendicular to r. Therefore, V1 and V2 are perpendicular to each other, thus their cross product shouldn't vanish
Could somebody explain what I have misunderstood? Thanks!

Comment: Why does $\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r}$ have to be in the direction of $\vec{r}$???? What if $\vec{r} = 3t\hat{x} + 2\hat{y}$?

Comment: Let's take a rotating electron in a B-field. As the electron moves in a circle, the **change** of the position is always perpendicular to $\vec r$.

Comment: I think I get it now, the example on the B-field was enlightening! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment so I am putting this out as an answer.

There is **no** reason why "$v_1$ being the differential(derivative) of $r$ should be *along* $r$".

$v_1$ and $v_2$ are the same. $r$ is the **position** of the particle and $r\times mv_{2}$ gives its angular momentum, where $v_2=\frac{dr}{dt}=v_1$

Another thing you must understand is that there is **no reason** why $v_2$ - the velocity of the particle should be along its position vector $r$.

You can simply change your coordinate system to change the angle between the position vector and the velocity.